# Custom validation messages for Session model in Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

What's the best way to override validation messages for login/password in the Session model in Authlogic?  In the User model Authlogic provides the merge_ methods to override validation options, but Session does not have anything like that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authlogic has it's own [I18n class](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/f2e95179acf87f11b44c7a58e6083cf84cddff27/Authlogic/I18n.html). Maybe it will help you? It uses by default [Rails' translation mechanism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) so it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: While I have no explicit need for Internationalization (app will never be used outside the US), I suppose that's the only way to go about it in Authlogic. It seems inconsistent to me that the overrides would exist in the User model but not for Sessions.  Thanks for your response!