# how to overwrite authlogic validation messages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm using Rails Authlogic in my application. i want to overwrite validation messages. validates_length_of and validates_format_of are working but validates_presence_of is not working for both login and password.

can someone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add a locale language file config/locales/es.yml to locales then add something like this:

```
es: 
  authlogic:
    error_messages:
      login_blank: No puede estar en blanco
      login_not_found: no es valido
      login_invalid: "debe utilizar sólo letras, numeros, espacios, y  .-_@ por favor."
      consecutive_failed_logins_limit_exceeded: Consecutive failed logins limit exceeded, account is disabled.
      email_invalid: debe ser similar a una dirección de correo electrónico.
      password_blank: No puede estar en blanco
      password_invalid: no es valido
      not_active: Tu cuenta no está activo
      not_confirmed: Su cuenta no se confirma
      not_approved: "Tu cuenta no está aprobada"
      no_authentication_details: Usted no proporcionó ningún detalle para la autenticación.
      email_invalid: "No es valido"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the validations failing for your `User` or `UserSession` model? Or both?

For the `User` model, ensure that you are calling `acts_as_authentic`:

```
class User
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

For the `UserSession` model, ensure that you're inheriting from the `Session` class:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

As for customizing the error messages, you can use the i18n approach as detailed below. Or, for the `User` model at least, you can do it in Ruby. See these Authlogic docs:

http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Login/Config
http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Password/Config

In those docs, you'll notice some methods beginning with "merge." Those should do the trick for you.

I couldn't find anything equivalent for the `Session` class. The comment in this Stack Overflow question suggests that it doesn't exist:

[Custom validation messages for Session model in Authlogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992552/custom-validation-messages-for-session-model-in-authlogic)